# Parse.com Facebook login for IOS not working

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I'm using the following standard code taken from Parse docs but when I hit the FB login button, I see the "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login." message even though I hit OK on the FB authentication page (the FB app is not installed on my simulator).

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouchHandler:(id)sender  {
// The permissions requested from the user
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];

// Login PFUser using Facebook
[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating]; // Hide loading indicator

    if (!user) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Uh oh. An error occurred: %@", error);
        }
    } else if (user.isNew) {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] animated:YES];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[UserDetailsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] animated:YES];
    }
}];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using someone else's account other than yours to log in through facebook, You have to go to your Facebook developer console and enable the sandbox mode. That should fix the issue. However, that will make the app live. If you do not want that to happen, add developer/testers to your app and you can test using added accounts. You can set these roles through  "Developer roles" option on the left.

Answer (score 0):

In my case if you asking for the basic information only you should set Permission to nil as it  include the default permissions , Otherwise you should include this key to your permission array to work @"publish_actions"